# Navbar border left & right issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Well I am truly stumped today, I am trying to recreate this Navbar:

http://www.autotrader.co.uk/

Now if you look at it, it has borders-left and borders-right for the "Buying" link. After digging about in the CSS I have worked out how they have made that possible. They have this HTML:

```
<ul class="navmain_holder">
</ul>
```

The developers have added a border-left to that element to create the border at the start of the nav bar.

Now if you take a look at this live header example of my site:

http://www.dealerbyte.co.uk/

The border is set to the left however if you look at the "Get Finance" link I can't add a right-border to it because then all the other elements will get that border which will cause some borders to appear 2px thick instead of one and as I am using Bootstrap the responsive CSS stops me from approaching this problem in some ways.

I'm sorry I haven't really explained my problem all that well hopefully someone will understand, any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: you need to put the border left on the ul and the border right on the li

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the last element with the following selector:

```
ul.nav > li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #475d88;
}
```

It selects only the last `li` element. Good luck!

**EDIT** here's a demo fiddle from Harry: http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/D2JzN/

**EDIT** as Pete has pointed out, you could also add the `border-left` just to the outer `ul` element and apply `border-right` to all the `li` elements. It's also worth pointing out that if you want to support IE8 the `last-child` selector is not supported I believe. So you might have to go this route, but from my testing it looks like you aren't trying to support IE8, which is probably better for your sanity. :)

Comment: You beat me to the answer. Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/D2JzN/) if you wish to add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for putting the demo together!

Comment: If you like the answer, don't forget to accept it :) Thanks Nick